# Add include paths to qt-creator for CMake project

Tags: cmake, ide, cross-platform, qt-creator

I am cross-compiling a CMake based project and want to use QT-Creator as the IDE. Build/Deploy/Run works fine but Qt-Creator seems to ignore the CMAKE_SYSROOT argument when trying to resolve system headers while browsing thru the source. I am aware of the INCLUDEPATH variable for qmake based projects but is there a way of achieving the same for CMake based pojects while cross-compiling ?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind -- figured it out. Was building for QNX. The build-chain needs the ENV variables QNX_HOST & QNX_TARGET set *before* even staring qtcreator. Setting them in the "Kit" set up wasn't enough.